# How receive data from POST in asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a problem trying to receive data from `POST` and return again in a list, this for probate what WORK

This is my code:

```
function Person(ID, name, lastname)
{
    var person = { ID: ID, name: name, lastname: lastname };            

    $.ajax({
        url: '/Form/save',
        type: 'post',
        data: person,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json"
    }).done(function (msg) {
        console.log('Person: '+ msg);
    }).fail(function (error) {
        console.log('ERROR: '+ error.error);
    }).always(function () {

    });
}
```

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult save()
{
    // I NEED YOU - get all data here and return
    string name = Request["name"].ToString();
    return Json(name, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to return it as JsonResult? Were you able to debug the save ActionResult?

Comment: What problem are you having?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When your are posting data to method in C# you need to have class defined with same parameters in your post method.

In your case your method will become

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult save(Person person)
{
    //Here your need to access person object to get the data 
    string name = person.name;
    return Json(name, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Now class person will be representation of what your sending from your client.
Again in your case Person class will be like

```
class Person 
{
  public int ID {get; set;}
  public string name {get; set;}
  public string lastname {get; set;}
}
```

So as mentioned in comments creating `class Person` in completely optional and you can skip that it just on of best practice. In that case your post method will look like

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult save(Object person)
{
    //Here your need to access person object to get the data 
    string name = person.name;
    return Json(name, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: you don't "need" a class, it is a best practice but it's not a "must"

Comment: Need to Stringify the parameters?

Comment: @SantiagoHernández: Agree. I just put that for better understanding. Chris: Do you mean person object in ajax need to stringify?

Answer (score 1):

It's work. I like use 
function Person(ID, name, lastname)
{
    var person = { ID: ID, name: name, lastname: lastname };

```
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("Controller","Action")',
    type: 'post',
    data: person,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json"
}).done(function (msg) {
    console.log('Person: '+ msg);
}).fail(function (error) {
    console.log('ERROR: '+ error.error);
}).always(function () {

});
```

}